# Am I using ncurses correctly for a Vector?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I programm a little game and it should be playable on the console. I use ncurses for that, the code compiles but when I start the game nothing is showed on the console. The gamearea is saved in a 2d Vector and the values are in this Vector I checked it, with the normal printf and without ncurses everything is fine but if I want to use ncurses nothing is printed on the Console.

```
for (auto const& i : gamearea) {
for (auto const& j : i){
  // Wall
  if (j == '#') {
    // printf("#\n");
    attron(5);
    mvprintw(_height, _width, " ");
    attroff(5);
  }
```

This is a piece of code from the Function, in this Function are 6 more if loops with nearly the same code.  gamearea is my 2d Vector and _height and _width are to variables which say how big the space should be. The Space replace the #.

What I want to know is, where I'm using the ncurses functions wrong? I have init the Terminal with all I need in an other function:

```
 void Play::initTerminal() {
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  curs_set(false);
  nodelay(stdscr, true);
  keypad(stdscr, true);
  start_color();
  use_default_colors();
  init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_BLACK);
  init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_GREEN);
  init_pair(3, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLUE);
  init_pair(4, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_YELLOW);
  init_pair(5, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_WHITE);
  init_pair(6, COLOR_RED, COLOR_RED);
  init_pair(7, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_CYAN);
}
```

Maybe I did something wrong in this function. I only used ncurses once before and there I used printf but this time I want to use the functions from ncurses right.
I didn't find something similar to this here.

Comment: Are you calling `refresh()`?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling refresh(). I have a seperated class which init the Terminal and all needed functions to play, there is the refresh. But it doesn't draw anything on the Terminal, only when I use printf, like the comment in the first code piece it prints the values on the console but only when I call the function directly in the Main method.

Comment: Without a complete example, we can only guess.  For instance, your main program might use threads, which won't work well.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your color pairs are wrong

```
init_pair (5, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_WHITE)
```

will write white characters on a white background.

Comment: That could correct an other problem. The problem here was that I used attron and attroff wrong.  I wrote attron(5) instead of attron(COLOR_PAIR(5));